# Understanding the VS2013 MVC5 SPA Template WebAPI Security Features

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, asp.net-identity

I am trying to understand the security features of the VS2013 MVC5 SPA Template WebAPI.

In Startup.Auth.cs there is this -

```
TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token")
```

and this -

```
AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/Account/Authorize")
```

In my understanding, the AuthorizeEndPointPath is for when your acting as a 3rd Party OAuth authorization server.

However how it is used in the template, the flow seems to be

1. Login via Forms Authentication
2. Redirect to a secure page
3. Javascript checks for a bearer token in the local storage, it doesn't exist, so it redirects to this Authorize endpoint.

   window.location = "/Account/Authorize?client_id=web&response_type=token&state=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.hash);
4. Logs into app with OAuth security, returns token, which will be passed on subsequent API requests.

The /Token endpoint never seems to be used. A prior version of this templated did an ajax post to /Token to login.  I have a similar situation where the website is secured via Forms authentication/cookies but the WebApi is secured by Bearer token.

Is the Authorize endpoint being used correctly in this SPA template - is this the correct pattern to follow?  It seems like the appropriate way to authenticate for bearer token security "internally" for the app would be a "client credentials grant" though not sure how to generate the "secret".

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm having the same issue where I cannot authenticate with Web API.

Comment: It's been awhile.  I believe example is doing an Oauth authentication with an Oauth provider like you'd do authenticating with google, for ex, but it happens to be the (local) site - the same site you are logging into via Forms Auth.  What it boils down to is Forms Auth is being used for MVC auth, and you need to get a bearer Token for WebAPI auth. The token can be done as outlined in the question, or by the /Token endpoint.  If it's the same security backend (credential database) I find it easier to just post to the /Token endpoint and get a token for the API and store this in local storage.

Comment: If I try and hit the /Token endpoint i receive {"error": "invalid_client"}. I must be missing something.

Comment: I bet you have a Startup.Auth.cs file, that you create some OAuthServerOptions. One of those options is Provider.  In my scenario, Provider is a class I wrote that inherits from OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider, and overrides GrantResourceOwnerCredentials, and ValidateClientAuthentication.  I bet this is where your error is coming from, it would be helpful for you to debug these overridden methods anyways and get an idea of the mechanics. Here is a simple example I just googled: http://www.hackered.co.uk/articles/asp-net-mvc-creating-an-oauth-client-credentials-grant-type-token-endpoint